# Python3: Adding multi column rows in empty pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

**My Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('input_file', header = None, delimiter="\t", names = ['chr', 'sTSS', 'eTSS', 'gene', 'clust1', 'clust2'])

row_filter_column_clust2_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = data.columns, index=data.index)
row_filter_column_clust2_1.append(data.loc[0]) #Row is not appended
print(row_filter_column_clust2_1) #Nothing is printed
```

**Problem description**
I want to add the multi-column rows from the imported file(input_file: see below) into the empty panda's data frame using the .loc function.

**input_file**

```
chr2    166760255   166760255   Cse1l_tss10 52  5426
chr2    166760282   166760282   Cse1l_tss9  52  5426
chr2    166885599   166886548   IRF8    150.18  5431
chr2    166885925   166885925   Znfx1_tss1  52  5433
```

**Expected Output**

```
chr2    166760255   166760255   Cse1l_tss10 52  5426
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably what you are looking after is the result of the `append`. So you should store that in some (probably the same) variable:

```
row_filter_column_clust2_1 = row_filter_column_clust2_1.append(data.loc[0])
```

Besides this I would like to help you with one more detail regarding the following row:

```
row_filter_column_clust2_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = data.columns, index=data.index)
```

here you should not add the `index` for creating an empty dataframe, it will add a lot of `NaN` entries for all the indices.

Also `.loc` will make the selection based on your index, so you will have a problem if you do not have a row with index `0`, if you want to select the first row irrespective of the index use `.iloc`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working fine. Just one more query is. While it printing the column is sorted. How can I print as it it I defined eariler.

Current Output:

         chr       clust1     clust2         eTSS                    gene                   sTSS
0       chr2     52.0       5426.0       166760255.0         Cse1l_tss10       166760255.0

Required Output:
        chr        sTSS               eTSS                gene                 clust1    clust2
0      chr2      166760255      166760255       Cse1l_tss10     52          5426

Comment: you can reorder the columns like this: df = df[['first_col', 'second_col',...]] to achieve column order 'first_col', 'second_col', ...

Comment: also pleas accept the answer if it solved your problem, thanks

Comment: My problem is solved. Thank you very much zsomko. Please let me know if any other way is to accept.

Comment: Happy to help. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) question about accepting answers.